# Как определить пользовательский литерал в Python? Например, type(37C) == <class 'temp'>

Tags: python, python-3.x

Могу ли я создать свой собственный класс/тип с моим собственным синтаксисом?

Например:

```py
mycar = bmw 
# или
mytemp = 37C

print(type(mycar))

print(type(mytemp))
```

Чтобы ответ был таким:

```
<class 'car'> 
# или
<class 'temp'>
```

А не таким:

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Можете! Вы правильно догадались, что можно создавать классы, которым присваиваются свойства. Погуглите «классы в python» и  почитайте. Это тема для лекции, не для ответа на форуме.

Comment: Думаю, ТС хочет сделать что-то типа [User-defined literals в C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal).

Comment: Да примерно так , я хочу создать свои синтаксис , но в коде Python

Comment: @HaykMalkhasyan Немного погуглив я нашёл только [предложение добавить эту фичу в язык](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2015-June/033871.html). Так что, думаю, на данный момент возможность определять пользовательские литералы в **чистом** `Python` отсутствует.

Comment: Никак, этой возможности в Python пока нет.

Answer (score 0):

Конечно можете, почитайте про ООП в Python. Это можно реализовать с помощью классов. Если вы про пользовательские литералы, то их ещё не ввели, но часто предлагают.